# Including a page with $.load() then adding a Class to an element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to include a side bar section to my site with navagation control. I'm currently using a  tag in my main page then calling

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
 });
```

That's working fine. After it loads I want to add a class to a div in the sidebar.html file. I try calling:

```
$("#sidebarItem1").addClass("active");
```

but the class isn't being added. However, if I open the console and type the same addClass call the class is added to the element.

How do I add a class to the elements that are being loaded in the other page?

Comment: `load()` is async, use the complete callback: `$("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html", function(){$("#sidebarItem1").addClass("active");});`

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue